# Synology NAS permissions for web server and FTP

Tags: ftp, permissions, webserver, permission-denied, synology

I'm trying to set up a Synology DS212j with DSM 5.0-4482 as a web server, with FTP access but I'm having permission issues. I manage to get the site up and running, and the SFTP server running. The problem is that I can't write to the server via FTP.
I tried giving R/W access to the web-folder to the (local) user connecting via FTP, when I do that I'm able to write to the server, but I can't access the page in the browser.

How do I set up permissions to give access both to the web server and the FTP user?

Answer (score 0):

I came up with one way:
I [mounted](http://hamrotechtips.blogspot.se/2007/12/mount-folder-inside-another-folder.html) the web folder in the users home folder. That gave the user permission to write, without taking permission from the web server.

This isn't ultimate, though. I still hope for a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

If one stumbles upon this question with the same problem. I had the same issue and fixed it by logging in with ssh into the Synology. The root directory for the ftp server is in my case root/volume1/web. You can change permissions with chmod if you have root permissions.

Open a terminal window an type the following (don't forget to enter the synology's ip address):

1. ssh admin@synology-ip-address
2. sudo su
3. chmod 775 /volume1/web/

775 is an example, give only permissions you need.

Hope it helps!

EDIT: this link gives a good idea how to add ftp users with special permissions
http://dimitar.me/how-to-create-an-ftp-user-and-allow-write-to-the-apache-root-directory-with-proper-permissions/